# Paginating with Python 2.7.9 Web Crawler

Tags: python-2.7, pagination, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to code a program in Python 2.7.9 to crawl and gather the club names, addresses and phone numbers from the website http://tennishub.co.uk/

The following code gets the job done, except for it doesn't move on to the subsequent pages for each location such as

```
/Berkshire/1
/Berkshire/2
/Berkshire/3
```

..and so on.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def tennis_club():
    url = 'http://tennishub.co.uk/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    for link in soup.select('div.countylist a'):
        href = 'http://tennishub.co.uk' + link.get('href')
        pages_data(href)


def pages_data(item_url):
    r = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    g_data = soup.select('table.display-table')

    for item in g_data:
        print item.contents[1].text
        print item.contents[3].findAll('td')[1].text
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all('td',{'class':'telrow'})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[5].findAll('td',{'class':'emailrow'})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        print item_url


tennis_club()
```

I have tried tweaking the code to the best of my understanding but it doesn't work at all.

Can someone please advise what do I need to do so that the program goes through all the pages of a location, collects the data and move on the to next location and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to put another `for` loop into this code:

```
for link in soup.select('div.countylist a'):
    href = 'http://tennishub.co.uk' + link.get('href')
    # new for loop goes here #
        pages_data(href)
```

If you want to brute force it you just have the for loop go as many times as the area with the most clubs (Surrey), however you would double, triple, quadruple, etc. count the last clubs for many of the areas.  This is ugly but you can get away with it if you are using a database where you don't insert duplicates.  However it is unacceptable if you are writing to a file.  In that case you will need to pull the number in parenthesis after the area Berkshire (39).  To get that number you can do a `get_text()` on the `div.countylist` which would change the above to

```
for link in soup.select('div.countylist'):
     for endHref in link.find_all('a'):
          numClubs = endHref.next
          #need to clean up endHrefNum here to remove spaces and parens
          endHrefNum = numClubs//10 + 1  #add one because // gives the floor
          href = 'http://tennishub.co.uk' + endHref.get('href') + / + endHrefNum
          pages_data(href)
```

(disclaimer: I didn't run this through bs4 so there might be syntax errors (and you might need to use something other than `.next`, but the logic should help you)